# JavaScript: Convert array based on value of sub item

Tags: javascript, json, loops, filter

In JavaScript I want to convert an array.

```js
[
    {
        'size' : 'm',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'm',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 's',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'm',
        'inStock' : false
    },
    {
        'size' : 'm',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'xl',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'xl',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'm',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'xxl',
        'inStock' : false
    },
    {
        'size' : 'xxl',
        'inStock' : false
    },
    {
        'size' : 'xxxl',
        'inStock' : false
    },
    {
        'size' : 'xxxl',
        'inStock' : true
    }
]
```

to this:

```js
[
    {
        'size' : 's',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'm',
        'inStock' : true
    },,
    {
        'size' : 'xl',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'xxl',
        'inStock' : true
    },
    {
        'size' : 'xxxl',
        'inStock' : true
    }
]
```

So I want to merge the array and if one or more item has 'inStock' set to true then this has to be set to that value else false.

I tried to loop through the array but that's not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this can be also used**

```
assign your array to var arr = [...your array];
var Newarray = arr.filter(function(data,i){
return data.inStock == true;
})

console.log(Newarray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using all the fancy new functions, objects and operators:

```
var map = new Map();
arr.forEach( (el) => {

  // make sure there is an entry in the mao
  let item = map.get( el.size );

   if( item ) {
     // item is already set
     item.inStock = el.inStock || item.inStock;
   } else {
     // new item
     map.set( el.size, el );
   }

});
let newArr = [ ... map.values() ];
```